# I'm developing a chat app and got this error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, mobile, build.gradle

I'm developing a chat app with flutter & firebase. However, I'm encountering an ERROR when trying to install it on my phone. It works smoothly when I run it on the web, in Chrome/Edge. I suspect it may be related to the build.gradle file. Could you please take a look? It's very important to me.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
> Build file 'C:\Users\cosmo\Documents\talkiey\android\app\build.gradle' line: 4
>
> What went wrong:
> Plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7dLd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdgUw.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: did you go through the android development setup in the flutter docs?

Comment: what is this? and frank so sorry!